# Using xPath expression to fetch first part of text using substring-before

Tags: xpath

I’m trying to capture only the *first* part of a string, but as a newbie, I’m confused on how to format the xPath expression. In the following table, I want only the attorney’s name in third row/third cell - before the break tag.

I can get to the cell with:

> //tr[contains(.,'Plaintiff')]/following-sibling::tr[contains(.,'Attorney:')]/td[3]

But how do I write the xPath expression that includes ‘substring-before’ to return everything before the < br > ?

This is the table I'm working with:

```
<table class="data">
  <thead>
   <tr class="head">
    <th scope="COL">Type</th>
    <th scope="COL">Name</th>
    <th scope="COL">Disposition</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd">
  <td class="">Plaintiff</td>
   <td class="">
   “Citibank, N.A.”
   <br>
   “None”
   </td>
   <td class="">CV-BT EntryJgmt-Clerk Default</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="even xh-highlight">
   <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class=""><b>Attorney:</b></td>
   <td class="">
   “Sue Yu”
   <br>
   “Dewey, Cheatum &amp; Howe Law Offices
   ,
   515 Burnitt St, Suite 400, San Jose, Ca  95119”
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
   <td>Defendant</td>
   <td>
   “Emma Royds”
   <br>
   “None”
   </td>
   <td>CV-BT EntryJgmt-Clerk Default</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without substring before :

```
//tr[contains(.,'Plaintiff')]/following-sibling::tr[contains(.,'Attorney:')]/td[3]/br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

this should works